# A non-measurable set with density $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

According to Lebesgue's Density Theorem:

> Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue outer measure, and let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. Then the limit: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\mu\left(A\cap\left(x-h,x+h\right)\right)}{2h}$$ exists and equals to either 0 or 1, for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is there a known example of a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ for which the claim above doesn't hold?

If not, Is there a known proof of existance of such a set?

(A set like this, if exists, is clearly non-measurable by the theorem above).

Comment: Hmm, good question. I was initially going to dismiss this question until I saw that $\mu$ referred to the Lebesque **outer measure** instead of the standard Lebesque measure. It still might be a trivial result for some, but not me.

Comment: Maybe a lead? There is that theorem from Sierpiński where he shows the existence of a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ the following way.
Let  $\mathscr{U}$ be some non-principal ultrafilter over $\mathbb{N}$; then define:
$$E=\left\{\sum_{n\in A}\!2^{-n-1}\ \Bigg|\ A\in\mathscr{U}
\right\}.$$
He shows that $E$ and $F=[0,1]\smallsetminus E$ are symmetric around $\frac12$.
If they were measurable they would have the same measure $\frac12$.
Using a _reductio ad absurdum_ reasoning he proves that if $E$ is measurable, then its measure must be 1.
(Now, this set $E$ has an outer measure…)

Comment: Somewhat relevant: [*A converse of Lebesgue's density theorem*](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/pjab1912/16/8/16_8_350/_article) by Shunji Kametani (1940) AND [*On Lebesgue's density theorem*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-03/S0002-9939-1950-0036816-1/) by Casper Goffman (1950) AND [*The construction of a Lebesgue measurable set with every density*](https://doi.org/10.2307/44153706) by Allan deCamp (1990-1991) AND [*Exceptional points for Lebesgue's density theorem on the real line*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810002719) by András Szenes (2011).

Comment: About as extreme as one can get, at least for the real line, is probably a 1917 result of Luzin/Sierpinski discussed in [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/119693/15780). Also, [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/836622/13130) discusses Goffman's 1950 paper a little and [this mathoverflow question and answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/171971/15780) provides a follow-up to that MSE answer.