# Construct a set with different upper and lower Lebesgue density at zero.

Tags: real-analysis

For $\delta >0,$let $I(\delta)$ be the segment $(- \delta, \delta) \subset \mathbb{R}.$ Given $\alpha,\beta,$ and $0 \leq \alpha < \beta \leq 1,$ construct a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ so that the upper and lower limits of 
$$m(E \cap I(\delta))/2 \delta$$ are $\beta$ and $\alpha$ repsectively as $\delta \rightarrow 0.$

This is a question from Rudin's book on Real and Complex Analysis and it has been taken up before here:
[Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with given metric density at zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14946/lebesgue-measurable-subset-of-mathbbr-with-given-metric-density-at-zero) . 
Yuval Filmus has posted an answer which I'm trying to verify, but I can't make it to work. In his answer, he sets $E$ to be the duplication around zero of
$$\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \left[\frac{1}{(2n)!}-\alpha\left(\frac{1}{(2n)!} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\right),\frac{1}{(2n)!}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}-\beta\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)!} - \frac{1}{(2n+2)!}\right),\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\right].$$

I have no problem with showing that $\beta$ and $\alpha$ can occur as limits, but I can't show that any limit must lie between $\beta$ and $\alpha.$

My questions are thus:
 1. Is the construction of Yuval correct? Does this work?
 2. If not, what is an example that does work?

**My attempt with Yuval's example**

Let us try to show that any limit must lie between $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ Say that $0< r <1$ and that $ \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!} < r \leq \dfrac{1}{(2n)!}.$ Then we have that $$m(E \cap I(1/(2n+1)!)) \leq m(E \cap I(r) ) \leq m(E \cap I(1/(2n)!)).$$
We have that $$m(E \cap I(1/(2n+1)!)) = 2\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty  \beta \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!} + 2 \sum_{k=n+2}^\infty \alpha \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!}$$ while
$$m(E \cap I(1/(2n)!)) = 2\sum_{k=n}^\infty  \alpha \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!} + 2 \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \beta \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!}.$$

We have  $$m(E \cap I(1/(2n+1)!))/(2r) \leq m(E \cap I(r) )/(2r) \leq m(E \cap I(1/(2n)!))/(2r).$$
We now want an upper and a lower bound on $m(E \cap I(r))/(2r).$For the upper bound, the obvious thing would be, since $(2n)!/2 \leq 1/(2r) < (2n+1)!/2$ would be to calculate  $$(2n+1)!/2m(E \cap I(1/(2n)!)).$$ This is $$(2n+1)!\sum_{k=n}^\infty  \alpha \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!} + (2n+1)! \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \beta \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!}.$$ But this upper bound is much too crude to give us anything valuable. I also tried by taking the midpoint of the interval $[1/(2n+1)!,1/(2n)!]$ but that similarily seemed to give me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To estimate $m(E\cap I(\delta))/2\delta$, consider the function
$$x\mapsto \frac{m(E\cap I(\delta+x))}{2(\delta+x)}.$$
Given a symmetric set $E$, we can for simplicity work with only $E\cap\mathbb{R}_+$, i.e. consider the function
$$M(x)=\frac{m(E\cap [0,\delta+x])}{\delta+x}.$$
Suppose first $x>0$. Then we can decompose $E\cap [0,\delta+x]$ into the parts $E\cap [0,\delta]$ and $E\cap[\delta,\delta+x]$. Whenever the interval $[\delta,\delta+x]$ is contained in $E$, using this decomposition gives
$$m(E\cap [0,\delta+x]) = m(E\cap[0,\delta])+m([\delta,\delta+x])=m(E\cap[0,\delta])+x.$$
We actually get the same formula also for $x<0$ whenever $[\delta+x,\delta]\subset E$.
Therefore, when $\delta$ is contained in an interval $\delta\in(a,b)\in E$, as long as $\delta+x$ is in the same interval, we have
$$M(x) = \frac{m(E\cap [0,\delta+x])}{\delta+x} = \frac{m(E\cap[0,\delta])+x}{\delta+x}.$$
Since $m(E\cap[0,\delta])\leq m([0,\delta])=\delta$, we get $M'(x)\geq 0$, so the function $M$ is non-decreasing near $\delta$. Hence given $\delta\in(a,b)\subset E$ we get the estimates $M(a-\delta)\leq M(0)\leq M(b-\delta)$, i.e.
$$\frac{m(E\cap [0,a])}{a}\leq\frac{m(E\cap [0,\delta])}{\delta}\leq \frac{m(E\cap [0,b])}{b}.$$
Applying similar reasoning when $\delta$ is on some interval $\delta\in(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus E$ of the complement of $E$, we get $M(x) = m(E\cap [0,\delta])/(\delta+x)$. Since this is non-increasing, we get
$$\frac{m(E\cap [0,b])}{b}\leq\frac{m(E\cap [0,\delta])}{\delta}\leq \frac{m(E\cap [0,a])}{a}.$$
Therefore when the set $E$ is comprised of disjoint intervals $[a_k-l_k,a_k]$, it suffices to compute the upper bound along the endpoints $a_k$, and the lower bound along the endpoints $a_k-l_k$.

More explicitly, by the previous estimates one gets
\begin{align}
\limsup_{\delta\to 0}\frac{m(E\cap [0,\delta])}{\delta} &= \limsup_{k\to \infty}\frac{m(E\cap [0,a_k])}{a_k}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_k}\sum_{n=k}^\infty l_k\quad\text{and}\\
\liminf_{\delta\to 0}\frac{m(E\cap [0,\delta])}{\delta} &= \liminf_{k\to \infty}\frac{m(E\cap [0,a_k-l_k])}{a_k-l_k}=\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_k-l_k}\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty l_k.
\end{align}
Getting the precise bounds $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the densities is then just a matter of fine-tuning the lengths $l_k$ and positions $a_k$ of the intervals.

Comment: You write "Hence for a symmetric set $E$, if $\delta$ is on some interval $\delta\in(a,b)\subset E$ of the set, you can estimate
$$\frac{m(E\cap I(a))}{a}\leq\frac{m(E\cap I(\delta))}{\delta}\leq \frac{m(E\cap I(b))}{b}.$$"
Would you mind expanding on why this is so? I'm being a bit slow here, but don't see immediately why this is true.

Comment: @Dedalus Consider the function $x\mapsto m(E\cap I(\delta+x)) / (\delta +x)$. If $\delta\in (a,b)\subset E$, then $m(E\cap I(\delta+x)) = m(E\cap I(\delta)) + x$, and the previous remark gives the estimate.

Comment: I trid to fine-tune the intervals as you said, but didn't manage. Would you mind filling in this? Also, did you check the example Yuval gave?

Answer (score 5):

I'll deal with the cases $0<\alpha < \beta <1.$ Suppose $b_1 > a_1 > b_2 > a_2 > \cdots \to 0.$ Let $E=\cup_n [a_n,b_n].$ For $0<x<b_1,$ define

$$f(x) = \frac{m(E\cap [0,x])}{x}.$$

Check that $f$ increases on each $[a_n,b_n],$ and decreases on each $[b_{n+1},a_n].$ Thus the maximum of $f$ on $[b_{n+1},b_n]$ is one of the values $f(b_n), f(b_{n+1}),$ while the minimum equals $f(a_n).$ Thus if we can find $a_n,b_n$ such that $f(b_n) = \beta, f(a_n) = \alpha$ for all $n,$ we'll be done.

Note the following:

$$\tag 1 f(b_n)=\frac{(b_n-a_n) + (b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) + \cdots  }{b_n}, $$ $$f(a_n)=\frac{(b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) + (b_{n+2}-a_{n+2})\cdots  }{a_n}.$$

It turns out that we can choose $a_n,b_n$ to be geometric sequences. Define

$$c = \frac{1-\beta}{1-\alpha}, b= c\frac{\alpha}{\beta}.$$

Put $b_n = b^n, a_n = cb^n.$ Then these $b_n,a_n$ do exactly what we want. To check this, use $(1)$ to see

$$f(b_n) = \frac{(1-c)b^n + (1-c)b^{n+1} + \cdots  }{b^n} = \frac{1-c}{1-b}.$$

Do some algebra to see the last fraction equals $\beta.$ The same kind of argument gives $f(a_n)=\alpha.$ That completes the proof.

I realize that some of this seems like rabbits out of hats, but it's really not that unintuitive. If you entertain the idea that geometric sequences $a_n,b_n,$ might work, even if the $a_n$ sequence is a fixed constant times the sequence $b_n,$ then the definitions of $b,c$ arise naturally.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for the case $0=\alpha<\beta$? when i try to replicate the idea here for this case the details get somewhat daunting

Comment: @user363464  For an idea, take $\beta = 1/2,$ and try $b_n = 1/n!, a_n = 1/(2\cdot n!).$

Comment: ah right. the exponential series.. thank you :)